# Adding new records to attachment match table from select number of features from feature class using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, attachments

I am seeking some ArcPy/Python help. I use the mobile app GIS Pro to collect data in the field, which allows me to export shapefiles containing a field called Photos, containing a list of names of photos associated with each feature. The list appears like this:

[image]

I am trying to create a tool that will

1. Import the shapefile into a project geodatabase
2. Add the features from the shapefile to a "master feature class"
3. Update an attachment match table to include the photos associated with the new features
4. Add the new attachments

I am struggling with step 3. There needs to be a new entry in the match table for each photograph. The match table contains the fields REL_OBJECTID & ATT_NAME. The REL_OBJECTID needs to coincide with the OID assigned to the feature after it has been merged into the "master feature class".

Answer (score 1):

Forget about fields in attachment table, Arcgis add attachments tool will populate them for you. Based on field names I assume you are using arcgis. Create new table with 2 fields: name - text long enough to store "observatin 1" etc, path - text long enough to store folder name where you saved your pictures + photo name.

InsC=arcpy.da.InserCursor (abovetable, ("name","path"))

with da.searchcursor (shapefile, ("name","photos")) as cursor:

for name, alist in cursor:

```
  alist = alist.split (",")

  for photo in alist:

     R = (name, os.path.join (folderWpictures,photo))

     InsC.insertRow(R)
```

Use table as match table in add attacments tool to your fgdb feature class.

Caution: fix rotation of your pictures, before attaching them. I use infraview batch convert. It understands rotation of pictures taken by mobile device